# Default value in Doctrine

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm

How do I set a default value in Doctrine 2?

Comment: @ORM\Column(name="foo", type="decimal", precision=7, scale=2, options={"default" = 0}) works (from the non-popular answer below)

Comment: @ORM\Column(name="is_activated", type="boolean",options={"default":0})
OR
@ORM\Column(name="is_activated", type="boolean",options={"default"= 0})

Comment: Ahmed this doesn't seem to work for booleans in Symfony 2.3.  However options={"default" = "0"}) does work, putting the integer in quotes.

Comment: If it's a boolean, why aren't you using:  options={"default":false}  ?

Answer (score 427, accepted):

Database default values are not "portably" supported. The only way to use database default values is through the `columnDefinition` mapping attribute where you specify the `SQL` snippet (`DEFAULT` cause inclusive) for the column the field is mapped to.

You can use:

```php
<?php
/**
 * @Entity
 */
class myEntity {
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Column(name="myColumn", type="string", length="50")
     */
    private $myColumn = 'myDefaultValue';
    ...
}
```

PHP-level default values are preferred as these are also properly available on newly created and persisted objects (Doctrine will not go back to the database after persisting a new object to get the default values).

Comment: but there is a problem here : What if I set a "datetime" type?

Comment: @artragis put your instanciation in the entity constructor

Comment: Care has to be taken with migrations using this approach as any existing rows will cause the migration to fail.

Comment: @Tamlyn Do you mean that if you add a new column, the migration won't set this default value to the pre-existing rows, or something else?

I think it's always sensible to set the value of a new column manually in your migration, unless they want to be null. It's possible existing rows will want a special value, not the default value for new rows.

Comment: @Tamlyn, @rjmunro, so when migrating, I noticed that if I add field which is `nullable=true` then it will obviously `NULL` in the updated DB once `doctrine:schema:update` is called (which is the expected behaviour). Whereas if the field added is 'nullable=false` then integer(ish) column values will be initialized to `0`. Didn't try yet `varchar`. And looks like upon `schema:update` I actually need to call separate script, which will process all rows and set valid value for the field. Any other advice on migration, guys?

Comment: On an update, if you do not include the saved/original value for that field, it will always get overwritten with the class variable (default)

Comment: Do not use the instantiation area to set variables... Trust me, bad thing will happen. Use the constructor area instead.

Comment: I reccomend to use the columnDefinition in the annotation, or somebody will use the mysql client or phpmyadmin and the values will be wrong...

Comment: IMHO that isn´t a default value - just an initial.
If you edit an entity and add a new column and want to set a default value, it won´t be set to the old entries, just to the new ones. So, the answer from iv3ndy is the correct one, if you want a really default value

Comment: you also need to do , options={"default" : 0} if you don't want to fuck up your migrations on a not-nullable field

Comment: As said by others in previous comments, this answer breaks your migrations if you add a non-nullable field to an existing entity, thus having to populate existing data with the default value. The solution is to add the default value in doctrine, as shown in answer from iv3ndy.

Answer (score 688):

```
<?php
#[ORM\Entity]
class myEntity {
    #[ORM\Column(options: ["default" => 0])]
    private int $myColumn;
    // ...
}
```

Or with the annotation syntax:

```
<?php
/**
 * @Entity
 */
class myEntity {
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="myColumn", type="integer", options={"default" : 0})
     */
    private $myColumn;
    ...
}
```

Note that this uses SQL `DEFAULT`, which is not supported for some fields like `BLOB` and `TEXT`.

Comment: Good catch! It seems there are no options={"default" = 0} option in official documentation

Comment: FYI, the `options` parameter is also useful for `unsigned` values. see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692686/doctrine-2-unsigned-value/14221973#14221973)

Comment: Very nice! This is very useful _in addition_ to having defaults in PHP (as per the accepted answer) when you are migrating between model versions and don't want pre-existing entities to get a null value for a newly-added field!

Comment: Does not support booleans. Also, may disappear in further Doctrine versions.

Comment: @wdev it supports booleans just fine with Doctrine 2.4 on Postgresql 8+

Comment: I use both this and the accepted answer to cover all bases. Also just a note that you can also do: `options={"default": 0}`
Be careful to use " and not ', as it causes errors in my version of doctrine.

Comment: This should be the selected answer!

Comment: @wdev as of 2015 (two years after your comment, it is now in the documentation [1].  However, your comment worries me. Do you know if it is actually slated for removal or did you base that on the fact that it was not in the docs at the time? [1]:http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-column

Comment: @Matt he probably said that because it was an undocumented feature, and undocummented features are prone to being removed. As it's documented now, you should be safe using it.

Comment: When working with migrations, this is definitely the desired solution, as otherwise a `doctrine:migrations:diff` will not understand that you have set a default value, since that only scans the annotation/metadata and not the PHP defaults.

Comment: This solution given by @iv3ndy is nicely working. After implementing it to add a default value 1 for a boolean entity property and when I checked the generated migration file, this line was added: $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE user CHANGE is_active is_active TINYINT(1) DEFAULT \'1\' NOT NULL');  Prior to this, any time I tweaked the migration file, all manually injected changes into migration file were asked to be reverted, of course because the entity file was still intact. But now, all is fine. :)

Answer (score 65):

Set up a constructor in your entity and set the default value there.

Comment: This certainly seems like the logical approach. Has anyone run into issues with setting up defaults in the constructor?

Comment: Doctrine's recommended solution: http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/faq.html

Comment: @cantera25 that should be the answer +1

Comment: this doesn't update existing entities if you add new field which needs to have default value. so no that shouldn't be the answer. depends on what exactly you need to do

Comment: It won't work on update purpose either. If you want to go back to the default value by just emptying the field (even for integer), unfortunately, it won't work.

Comment: New link to the FAQ on that topic: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/faq.html#entity-classes

Answer (score 61):

Use:

```
options={"default":"foo bar"}
```

and not:

```
options={"default"="foo bar"}
```

For instance:

```
/**
* @ORM\Column(name="foo", type="smallint", options={"default":0})
*/
private $foo
```

Comment: I'm sorry, you are right. So you can find an explanation on this page: [doctrine-orm annotations-reference](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#column)

Comment: The link in the above comment is dead. Try [this one](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/annotations-reference.html#column).

Answer (score 58):

### Update

One more reason why **read the documentation** for Symfony will never go out of trend. There is a simple solution for my specific case and is to set the `field type` option `empty_data` to a default value.

Again, this solution is only for the scenario where an empty input in a form sets the DB field to null.

#### Background

None of the previous answers helped me with my specific scenario but I found a solution.

I had a form field that needed to behave as follow:

1. Not required, could be left blank. (Used 'required' => false)
2. If left blank, it should default to a given value. For better user experience, I did not set the default value on the input field but rather used the html attribute 'placeholder' since it is less obtrusive.

I then tried all the recommendations given in here. Let me list them:

- Set a default value when for the entity property:

```php
<?php
/**
 * @Entity
 */
class myEntity {
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Column(name="myColumn", type="string", length="50")
     */
    private $myColumn = 'myDefaultValue';
    ...
}
```

- Use the options annotation:

```php
@ORM\Column(name="foo", options={"default":"foo bar"})
```

- Set the default value on the constructor:

```php
/**
 * @Entity
 */
class myEntity {
    ...
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->myColumn = 'myDefaultValue';
    }
    ...
}
```

None of it worked and all because of how Symfony uses your Entity class.

#### IMPORTANT

**Symfony form fields override default values set on the Entity class.** 
Meaning, your schema for your DB can have a default value defined but if you leave a non-required field empty when submitting your form, the `form->handleRequest()` inside your `form->isValid()` method will override those default values on your `Entity` class and set them to the input field values. If the input field values are blank, then it will set the `Entity` property to `null`.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#handling-form-submissions

#### My Workaround

Set the default value on your controller after `form->handleRequest()` inside your `form->isValid()` method:

```php
...
if ($myEntity->getMyColumn() === null) {
    $myEntity->setMyColumn('myDefaultValue');
}
...
```

Not a beautiful solution but it works. I could probably make a `validation group` but there may be people that see this issue as a **data transformation** rather than **data validation**, I leave it to you to decide.

---

#### Override Setter (Does Not Work)

I also tried to override the `Entity` setter this way:

```php
...
/**
 * Set myColumn
 *
 * @param string $myColumn
 *
 * @return myEntity
 */
public function setMyColumn($myColumn)
{
    $this->myColumn = ($myColumn === null || $myColumn === '') ? 'myDefaultValue' : $myColumn;

    return $this;
}
...
```

This, even though it looks cleaner, **it doesn't work**. The reason being that the evil `form->handleRequest()` method does not use the Model's setter methods to update the data (dig into `form->setData()` for more details).

Comment: This answer should go to the top for sure. Form component uses PropertyAccessor to get and set the values for your properties. Maybe the property accessor should use the methods when they are available?

Comment: boolean columns don`t support defaults from php, so only annotations

Comment: This is the only solution that worked when info is coming from forms. Also I disagree with above comments concerning boolean. They do not accept the default annotation.

Comment: Symfony form component **uses** model setters but only when _model format_ data of the form differs with data returned by corresponding getter of model object instance. If you have your custom setter/getter methods - use "property_path" form option (will be handled by PropertyAccessor) or custom DataMapper (allows to manually define data transfer routine between form and model object).

Comment: This question is about doctrine, not symfony, so this answer isn't really on topic.

Comment: I created Custom Enum Type, set default option this way: `@ORM\Column(type="statusVisibility", nullable=true, options={"default": StatusVisibilityType::DEFAULT_VALUE})`. it generated following Migration code:`ALTER TABLE status ADD visibility ENUM('ADMIN', 'USER', 'PUBLIC') DEFAULT 'ADMIN' COMMENT '(DC2Type:statusVisibility)'`

Comment: I'm a bit confused by this answer. Starts sayng that `empty_data` is the solution (an example would be very usefull), but then says that the workaround is to modify  `form->is valid()`.

Answer (score 23):

Here is how to do it in PHP 8 using [attributes](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.11/reference/attributes-reference.html).

```php
#[ORM\Column(type: Types::BOOLEAN, nullable: false, options: ['default' => false])]
#[Assert\NotNull()]
private bool $isFavorite = false;
```

Comment: This has to be higher..

Answer (score 18):

The workaround I used was a `LifeCycleCallback`. Still waiting to see if there is any more "native" method, for instance `@Column(type="string", default="hello default value")`.

```php
/**
 * @Entity @Table(name="posts") @HasLifeCycleCallbacks
 */
class Post implements Node, \Zend_Acl_Resource_Interface {

...

/**
 * @PrePersist
 */
function onPrePersist() {
    // set default date
    $this->dtPosted = date('Y-m-d H:m:s');
}
```

Comment: For future readers, don't rely on lifecycle callbacks :) even Marco Pivetta is against them.

Comment: Warning! If the Entity has already set the dtPosted property, then your code will simply overwrite the property. Always use accessors if they exist! `if (!$this->getDtPosted()) { $this->setDtPosted(new \DateTime()); }`

Comment: @emix can you explain?

Answer (score 15):

You can do it using xml as well:

```
<field name="acmeOne" type="string" column="acmeOne" length="36">
    <options>
        <option name="comment">Your SQL field comment goes here.</option>
        <option name="default">Default Value</option>
    </options>
</field>
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is how I solved it for myself. Below is an Entity example with default value for MySQL. However, this also requires the setup of a constructor in your entity, and for you to set the default value there.

```
Entity\Example:
  type: entity
  table: example
  fields:
    id:
      type: integer
      id: true
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
    label:
      type: string
      columnDefinition: varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'default_value' COMMENT 'This is column comment'
```

Comment: With this line in my config Doctrine tries to drop the default on the column everytime I run. php app/console doctrine:schema:update

Comment: This is the worst answer here. `columnDefinition` goes directly agains the purpose of having an ORM, which is abstraction from the database. This solution will break portability, will keep your software dependant on your DB vendor and will also break Doctrine Migrations tools.

Comment: @PedroCordeiro I completely agree with you. This is just a fast solution until another issue rises.

Answer (score 8):

None of this worked for me. I found some documentation on doctrine's site that says to set the value directly to set a default value.

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/faq.html#how-can-i-add-default-values-to-a-column

```
private $default = 0;
```

This inserted the value I wanted.

Comment: Please change the link to http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/faq.html See Point 3.2.2. How can I add default values to a column?

Comment: Correct link: [Doctrine v.2.6. Reference. FAQ. How can I add default values to a column?](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/faq.html#how-can-i-add-default-values-to-a-column)

Answer (score 7):

Works for me on a mysql database also:

```
Entity\Entity_name:
    type: entity
    table: table_name
    fields: 
        field_name:
            type: integer
            nullable: true
            options:
                default: 1
```

Comment: In annotation format for whom is interested:

@ORM\Column(name="Entity_name", type="integer", options={"default"="1"})

Answer (score 3):

Adding to @romanb brilliant answer.

This adds a little overhead in migration, because you obviously cannot create a field with not null constraint and with no default value.

```php
// this up() migration is autogenerated, please modify it to your needs
$this->abortIf($this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getName() != "postgresql");

//lets add property without not null contraint        
$this->addSql("ALTER TABLE tablename ADD property BOOLEAN");

//get the default value for property       
$object = new Object();
$defaultValue = $menuItem->getProperty() ? "true":"false";

$this->addSql("UPDATE tablename SET property = {$defaultValue}");

//not you can add constraint
$this->addSql("ALTER TABLE tablename ALTER property SET NOT NULL");
```

With this answer, I encourage you to think why do you need the default value in the database in the first place? And usually it is to allow creating objects with not null constraint.

Answer (score 3):

If you use yaml definition for your entity,
the following works for me on a postgresql database:

```
Entity\Entity_name:
    type: entity
    table: table_name
    fields: 
        field_name:
            type: boolean
            nullable: false
            options:
                default: false
```

Comment: What if you didn't use `$entity->setFieldName()` before flushing? Doctrine seems to define the default value at null. The only solution in yaml is to define the default value *IN* the entity class which seems dumb to me since it's already defined in the yaml ... -_-

Answer (score 1):

While setting the value in the constructor would work, using the Doctrine Lifecycle events might be a better solution.

By leveraging the `prePersist` Lifecycle Event, you could set your default value on your entity only on initial persist.

Comment: Using lifecycle events is considered a `hack`. Never rely on hacks.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same problem. I wanted to have the default value from the database into the entities (automatically). Guess what, I did it :)

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by JetBrains PhpStorm.
 * User: Steffen
 * Date: 27-6-13
 * Time: 15:36
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
 */

require_once 'bootstrap.php';

$em->getConfiguration()->setMetadataDriverImpl(
    new \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\DatabaseDriver(
        $em->getConnection()->getSchemaManager()
    )
);

$driver = new \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\DatabaseDriver($em->getConnection()->getSchemaManager());
$driver->setNamespace('Models\\');

$em->getConfiguration()->setMetadataDriverImpl($driver);

$cmf = new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\DisconnectedClassMetadataFactory();
$cmf->setEntityManager($em);
$metadata = $cmf->getAllMetadata();

// Little hack to have default values for your entities...
foreach ($metadata as $k => $t)
{
    foreach ($t->getFieldNames() as $fieldName)
    {
        $correctFieldName = \Doctrine\Common\Util\Inflector::tableize($fieldName);

        $columns = $tan = $em->getConnection()->getSchemaManager()->listTableColumns($t->getTableName());
        foreach ($columns as $column)
        {
            if ($column->getName() == $correctFieldName)
            {
                // We skip DateTime, because this needs to be a DateTime object.
                if ($column->getType() != 'DateTime')
                {
                    $metadata[$k]->fieldMappings[$fieldName]['default'] = $column->getDefault();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

// GENERATE PHP ENTITIES!
$entityGenerator = new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\EntityGenerator();
$entityGenerator->setGenerateAnnotations(true);
$entityGenerator->setGenerateStubMethods(true);
$entityGenerator->setRegenerateEntityIfExists(true);
$entityGenerator->setUpdateEntityIfExists(false);
$entityGenerator->generate($metadata, __DIR__);

echo "Entities created";
```

Comment: Coming back to this from over a few years I recommend you not to use this approach, it really is a hacky hack.

Comment: Since you do not recommend your own answer, you might just as well delete it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Be careful when setting default values on property definition! Do it in constructor instead, to keep it problem-free. If you define it on property definition, then persist the object to the database, then make a partial load, then not loaded properties will again have the default value. That is dangerous if you want to persist the object again.