# Symfony2, Doctrine, persist with predefined value

Tags: symfony, doctrine, persist

is there a simple way to persist an entity with all values = 0? My entity has an extreme amount of rows ... typing ->setBlabla(0) for that amount of rows..puh..

Is there an "easier" way?

Regards

Comment: Could you provide use what have you done yet? Maybe an easy way be getting the repository and create an update query

Comment: possible duplicate of [Default value in Doctrine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3376881/default-value-in-doctrine)

Comment: Well, its an entity with like 226 columns. getters/setters. I'd like to predefine a value for every column. If i persist a new row the value for every column has to be 0. Writing it down by hand... guess i sound lazy, but i feel like there's a way around it.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Thx Wouter!

Comment: Hm, i've set options={"default"= 0}, when i insert a row via mysql it works fine, but when i persist a new row via doctrine/em, it puts "null" instead of "0". Any idea?

Comment: class MySillyEntity { protected $var1 = 0; protected $var2 = 0;  and so on.

Comment: When you set `options={"default"= 0}` you also need to set `nullable=false` for them, too

Answer (score 2):

The doctrine docs suggest to define default values via entity properties:

```
class User
{
    const STATUS_DISABLED = 0;
    const STATUS_ENABLED = 1;

    private $status = self:STATUS_DISABLED;
}
```

see FAQ http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/faq.html#how-can-i-add-default-values-to-a-column

I would prefer to set all properties default values in entity class constructor:

```
class User
{
    const STATUS_DISABLED = 0;
    const STATUS_ENABLED = 1;

    private $status;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->status = self::STATUS_DISABLED;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a default value for each field and use `nullable=false` to force it insert the default value; like this

```
@ORM\Column(name="column_name", type="integer", nullable=false, options={"default" = 0})
```

Or you can create a service `prePresist` to set the "0" value to empty fields before persist be fired. Take at look at 
[Doctirn2 Lifecycle Events](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events)
[Symfony2 Event Listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html)