# Doctrine 2 setting constructor values

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a problem in setting initial property values in an doctrine 2 entity:

```
<?php

/**
 * Class Saving
 *
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="saving", options={"engine" = "NDBCLUSTER"})
 */
class Saving
{
    /**
     * @Column(name="balance", type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2)
     * @var decimal
     */
    private $_balance;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_balance = 10;
    }
}

?>
```

In this how to initialize balance correctly? Do I have to use postLoad?

Comment: Doctrine does not call the constructor during hydration.  Hence the problem.  For your specific case just use private $balance = 10;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Cerad said, you should just put that value in your property declaration. This is also [suggested solution from Doctrine](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/faq.html#how-can-i-add-default-values-to-a-column).

You may also check the discussion here: [Default value in Doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3376881/default-value-in-doctrine)