# Add default value to a manyToOne field on doctrine yml mapping

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, yaml

I'd need to know how to add a default value for a manyToOne field on my entity.orm.yml mapping  in Symfony. This code is not working:

```
    manyToOne:
    usertype:
        targetEntity: Usertype
        cascade: {  }
        mappedBy: null
        inversedBy: null
        joinColumns:
            UserType:
                referencedColumnName: ID
        orphanRemoval: false
        options:
            default: 1
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Default value in Doctrine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3376881/default-value-in-doctrine)

Comment: I think it's not duplicated, as none of them solves a manytoOne via yaml ...