# why mysql accept null for non-nullable fields

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am learning laravel 5.1 through  [laracast fundamentals series](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals) and in episode 7 that talk about migrations, i built a table with migration like this:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('body');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->timestamp('published_at');
    });
}
```

and as it says in the episode 10, when i add an article to database through a form  that don't have a field for `published_at` timestamp, then this should not work and should through an exception that `Not Null constraint failed` But incredibly the article added to table.
When i look at the table in phpmyadmin structure for the `published_at` column it didn't checked the `null` checkbox, so it shouldn't accept null? **is this true?**
But then i noticed that the migration sets a default value to `0000-00-00 00:00:00` for `published_at` column. **why?!** and **will this override the NULL condition?**
Then i tried to set the default value to `none` and still the null is not checked. and again i tried to add an article without `published_at` fields But again a new row added to table with `published_at` value set to `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.
any explanation?

---

I am using wampserver with `mysql v5.6.17` , `php v5.5.12`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT @@SQL_MODE;`.

If you don't see one of the [Strict SQL Modes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict) enabled, then MySQL is using its older behavior, and coercing invalid values into something valid to allow the row to be inserted.

> If strict mode is not in effect, MySQL inserts adjusted values for invalid or missing values and produces warnings.

Default configuration files shipped with official MySQL Server 5.6 had `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` enabled.  WAMP may not have followed that same convention, perhaps for backward-compatibility reasons... but the configuration can be changed.

Comment: thanks, as you said i have this for mine `@@SQL_MODE = 
NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION` and seems that the same things happen here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26035507/1333160

Answer (score 3):

All database types have default values. When you create record and fill only title, then body will be set to empty string, and timestamps to "empty" date what is exactly `0000-00-00 00:00:00`. If you made those fields nullable and set `->default(null)` for them you will have null values for them in this case.

You can also read about [Default values for types in MySql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-type-defaults.html)

Comment: Thanks Marcin, I dont have a textbox for `published_at` in my form so when i submit that wouldn't that be `null` in the query?  or will that be an empty string?

Comment: And also i **did not** set that field to `nullable`

Comment: @osyan If you `published_at` is not nullable, when you don't fill it you will get `0000-00-00 00:00:00` because you haven't set any other default value. You could set it using `->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'))` and then when you don't fill it you will get by default current date and time instead of zeros

Comment: i got the point, but i am still Confused about why in the same situation it through an exception in that video. can this be because of Differences between sqlite and mySql ?

Comment: @osyan I see but I don't know why is that. I use almost all the time MySql and unfortunately have no more time to test this.