# How to use a default value for a datetime in Doctrine and mongoDb

Tags: mongodb, doctrine, symfony

working with doctrine and mongodb, I would like to set a datetime to a default value (new Datetime()) only when the record is create and only if no value is passed? Can I do this with annotations?

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Default value in Doctrine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3376881/default-value-in-doctrine)

Answer (score 0):

No, you would do this in the `__construct()` method
of the mapped Entity class. This way every time you call
new `EntityClass()` it will be set. Long before any doctrine persistence kicks in.

Just:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->dateProperty = new \DateTime()
}
```

Comment: thanks but I need to do this only when the record is created, not updated. I solved doing a find before the persist statement.

Comment: This it actually what it does. Doctrine does not call the Constructor when fetching entities from the database.

Comment: *Doctrine does not call the Constructor when fetching entities from the database* Are you sure? I think that the constructor is called but the value of `dateProperty` will be overwritten by value fetched from the database.

Comment: @A.L Yeah pretty much. The properties are set by reflection when fetching via ObjectManager.