# handle request of incomplete missing fields symfony form

Tags: forms, symfony, request

I have created a small Symfony (Sf3.2 + php7) web with a Task Entity. I have my controller where I have a new action to create a new task. Everything is fine. Now, some of the form fields are not necessary to be filled (created date, for example). So I have removed from my `taskType`:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->add->('name')->add('description');
}
```

Now my form looks exactly as I want. The surprise is that when I submit it  my controller pass it to doctrine,and every missing field is write as a NULL. NO!, I don't want that, what I wanted is my default mysql value.

Ok, I read the doc. There seems to be two ways of handling data:

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
$form->submit($request->request->get($form->getName()));
```

I've found in the API, (not in the doc) that submit have a second parameter, a boolean:

API says:

```
bool    $clearMissing   Whether to set fields to NULL when they are missing in the submitted data.
```

Great! this is exactly what I need. Lets see it:

```
public function newAction(Request $request) {
    $task = new Task();

    $form = $this->createForm('myBundle\Form\TaskType', $task);
    $form->submit($request->request->get($form->getName()), false);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {


        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($task);
        $em->flush();
        $response = new Response();
        $response->setContent(json_encode(array(
            'data' => 'success',
        )));
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return $response;

        return $this->redirectToRoute('task_success');
    }
    return $this->render('task/new.html.twig', array(
                'task' => $task,
                'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Well, after tried everything I always get NULL in all missing fields. What am I doing wrong.

Thank you, Caterina.

I'm afraid there must be something more. And I was thinking that perhaps is not Doctrine the solution. The Symfony log shows me the insert and it's setting a Null in every empty field, on empty fields and missing fields. In fields like status i could set a default value, at doctrine level, but if I want to set created_at field, I suppose that must be Mysql the responsible is setting current timeStamp.

Anyway this is my ORM property status from Task Entity.

```
/**
 * @var \scrumBundle\Entity\Taskstatus
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="scrumBundle\Entity\Taskstatus")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="status", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="integer", nullable=false,options={"default":1})
 */
private $status;
```

And this is the property id from TaskStatus:

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false, options={"default":1})
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;
```

As you see I tried to follow your advise of setting the option default value. I've tried to create to set the form with handleRequest and submit with same result

```
$task = new Task();
$form = $this->createForm('scrumBundle\Form\TaskType', $task);
//$form->handleRequest($request);
$form->submit($request->request->get($form->getName()), false);
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
```

I even tried to debug step by step submit function, a real Hell, because submit is a recursive function to much complex for me.

Ok , again thank for you time. 
Regards, Cate

PS. Sorry about my poor english.;^)

Comment: You need to explicitly set the defaults in your Entity.  Doctrine is always going to persist all fields from your entity so they will still be ` null` regardless of your form.  Set a default on your ORM column definition, a LifecycleCallback, or your entity's constructor.  Take a look here for some solutions. - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3376881/default-value-in-doctrine

Comment: Thank you very much! I had suspects about my entity. As soon I try it, i'll tell you

Comment: Symfony 1 - Cate 0, see my edits. please help

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - when you persist a PHP object through Doctrine, you must have absolutely every value set that you want.  If your PHP object has null fields, Doctrine will manually set them as `null` in your entity.  Doctrine doesn't assume that just because a value is `null` in your PHP object, that you don't want it included on your `INSERT` statement.  This is because `null` is a perfectly valid SQL value.

So, whatever your PHP object is at the time of insert is exactly what is going to be inserted into your database, `null` values and all.

When you are editing an entry, Doctrine will only update the fields that are different, so this isn't a concern.  Your concern is when persisting entities.

The easiest solution is to copy your MySQL default value into your PHP entity.  Like one of these many ways:

```
// set default value on the variable itself
public $someVar = 100;

// set default values in the constructor (so when creating a new entry)
public function __construct()
{
    $this->createdAt = new \DateTime();
    $this->isActive  = true;
}
```

You can also use [Lifecycle Callbacks](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/lifecycle_callbacks.html) to set when inserting a new entry:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Task
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     */
    public function setCreatedAtValue()
    {
        $this->createdAt = new \DateTime();
    }
}
```